# Can healers tell if a team mate is out of range in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I have never played Heroes of the Storm, but I understand that whether somebody is in range of a heal is an important mechanic.

Can a healer tell somehow if a teammate is in range or out of range of heal?

Is it possible to try to cast a heal on a player and get an out of range error, or does the system make it impossible to do this (for example, by greying out the spell so it is unclickable)?

Answer (score 7):

Pressing the corresponding ability will show the user a targeting circle -- anything within the circle is within range, and anything outside of it is not -- and the same is true of healing abililties.

Something I often do when playing as a healer is to "Pre-cast" my heals before an engagement, so that the ability is ready to cast and I have the targeting circle while dancing around the edge of combat.

If you're looking for something similar to how MMO RPGs handle out of range abilities (such as a small red dot, or greying out of the ability, Heroes of the Storm has no such indicators, at least in part because of how it handles unit selection). Instead, trying to cast on an out-of-range unit will move your hero towards the unit until they are within range, and *then* cast.

Of course, individual heroes / heal spells might change this - LiLi's healing spell, for-instance, auto-targets, and if LiLi herself is at full HP, the ability will gray out and prevent casting, rather than allow you to cast with zero targets.

Comment: Of course, at higher levels, you won't need the targetting circle as you get a feel for the general range of the ability, and you'll be using one-tap casting on abilities to activate them faster.

Comment: To add this, LiLi's heal will always target the lowest hp character around her, and that character is signified by a symbol underneath the characters feet - it looks like a green glowing aura.

Answer (score 0):

With Lili you can see a target circle on the team mate with the lowest HP.
With Lucio you can see the healing circle.

Aside from those two, I can't think of anyone else that would have a range indicator that you can see on quick cast.